# collectionViewをスクロールするとcellのsubviewが別のcellに移動する

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

collectionViewをスクロールするとcellのsubviewが別のcellに移動して困っております。

カメラロールの写真を取得し、collectionviewへ順に配置。
配置されたcellをタップするとtwitterのようにsubviewをcellへ追加するという処理を書いています。

```
#pragma mark - UICollectionViewDataSource

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    PHAsset *asset = self.assets[indexPath.item];

    CameraRollCell *cell = (CameraRollCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cameraRollCellID forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [self.imageManager requestImageForAsset:asset
                                 targetSize:self.cellSize
                                contentMode:PHImageContentModeDefault
                                    options:nil
                              resultHandler:^(UIImage *result, NSDictionary *info) {
                                  if (result) {
                                      cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:result];
                                  }
                              }];

    return cell;
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    PHAsset *asset = self.assets[indexPath.item];

    CameraRollCell *cell = (CameraRollCell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell selectPhoto];
}
```

そう思い、このような処理を書きました。`selectPhoto`を呼ぶことで、カスタムセル内にある、自らにsubviewを追加するという処理が走ります。

追加するとこのようになります。
[image: 正常時]

追加までは無事完了するのですが、collectionviewをスクロールすると、imageViewはそのままに、その追加されたsubViewが別のcellに移動してしまいます。
[image: 異常時]

どのようにすればこの不具合は起こらなくなるでしょうか？
ご回答、よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

画像が取得された時にセルが別のセルになったり、再利用されたセルに以前のUIImageViewが乗ったままになっているのではないでしょうか。

UIImageViewは初めからセルにのせておいて、画像をセットする時にテーブルからセルをindexPathで取得して所定の行のセルに画像をセットすると良いのではないでしょうか。以下のリンク先はUITableViewの例ですが参考になると思います。
[ios - Async image loading from url inside a UITableView cell - image changes to wrong image while scrolling - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16663618/async-image-loading-from-url-inside-a-uitableview-cell-image-changes-to-wrong)

Comment: imageViewはそのままにsubviewだけが移ってしまうのです。
すみません、折角回答して頂いたのに、質問内容があやふやでうまく伝わっていなかったようです。
編集して再投稿致しましたので、もしよろしければ再度見て頂けると幸いです。

Comment: おそらく同様の原因で、セルに載せたビューが再利用されたセルに載ったままになっているのではないでしょうか。selectPhoto載せたビューをcollectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:で削除するなりprepareForReuseメソッドをオーバーライドして削除するなりすると良いと思います。
selectPhotoで載せるビューを初めからカスタムセルに載せておいてhiddenで表示非表示をさせるほうほうの方が簡単かもしれませんが。

Comment: 再利用される際にaddされたsubviewを削除するという認識でよろしいですかね。
hiddenのほうが簡単そうですね…そちらの線もあたってみます。
ご回答ありがとうございました。